# How to set the session timeout in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, session-timeout

I don't have much Zend experience and want to change someone's login code in Zend to make the session not expire.

It seems the code is basic behavior:

```
    $adapter = $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter();
    $adapter->setIdentity($email)->setCredential($password);

    $result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();
```

What do I have to do to make the session not expire or to at least set the session for a specific time?

Right now the user doesn't stay logged in for long, I think perhaps it is just relying on default php settings behavior like the standard 24 minutes for the gc_maxlifetime.

What is the connection between Zend_Session and AuthService?

Comment: The question is titled _How to set the session timeout in **Zend Framework 2**_ but it's about ZF1 !!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is extending the session cookie lifetime. For that you could use the `rememberMe()` function. Do this after authenticating the user :

```
Zend_Session::rememberMe(1209600); //1209600/3600 = 336 hours => 336/24 = 14 days
```

But extending the session cookie lifetime will not have an effect because the server will not recognize that cookie after `gc_maxlifetime` time elapsed.

To deal with this, you must ensure the PHP `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting is at least the same value as the value you passed to `rememberMe()`.

I don't know if it's good practice or not but you can increase the `PHP Session Garbage Collection Time`.

In your `Bootstrap.php` file, you can do this :

```
protected function __initSession() {
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1209600);  // maxlifetime = 14 days
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
Zend_Session::start();
}
```

Or in the `.htaccess` file : (for 14 days)

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1209600
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how to set the session timeout :

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace( 'Zend_Auth' );
$session->setExpirationSeconds( 60 ); // 60 seconds
```

Comment: Your code can be used to expire a value *sooner* than the default, but I don't think it will *extend* a session beyond `session.gc_maxlifetime` which is what the original poster is asking.

Answer (score 0):

here is how to set the session timeout :

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace( 'Zend_Auth' );
$session->setExpirationSeconds( 60 ); // 60 seconds
```

This works great for me.